# Deleted all responsibilities in Siebel

Tags: crm, siebel

I was playing with Siebel WebClient and accidentally deleted all the responsibilities that I was assigned to. Now when I log in see nothing in my WebClient since I have no responsibilities. Is it possible to configure responsilibities in Siebel Tools? Or how can I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responsibilities are completely runtime, used for access control, and cannot be inserted via Tools. If you are on the Siebel Server, you could ask someone else with Admin Responsibility to your Employee Record. If that's not possible,or if you are on your local db, you will have to get this inserted directly into the d-base.

Try this SQL:

INSERT INTO SIEBEL.S_PER_RESP  ( 
      ROW_ID, 
      MODIFICATION_NUM, 
      CREATED_BY, 
      LAST_UPD_BY, 
      CREATED, 
      LAST_UPD, 
      DB_LAST_UPD, 
      DB_LAST_UPD_SRC, 
      CONFLICT_ID, 
      PER_ID, 
      RESP_ID, 
      PER_LAST_NAME, 
      PER_FST_NAME) 
VALUES ('3-30PCBP', '0', '3-2BIS4F', '3-2BIS4F', '01-JAN-2001', '01-JAN-2001', '01-JAN-2001', 'User', '0', (select row_id

from 
siebel.s_user 
where login = 'YOUR_LOGIN_ID'), (select row_id 
from 
siebel.S_RESP 
where name = 'Siebel Administrator'), '*', '*');

commit;

Do replace YOUR_LOGIN_ID. This insert statement will insert the Siebel Administator reponsibility directly, after which you should be able to login.

Answer (score 0):

No we can't configure responsibilities in tools.You can assign responsibility to your user with any other user having Admin responsibility.